# Is Gwaeron Windstrom a god or a demigod?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Gwaeron Windstrom is listed as a Forgotten Realms God of Tracking in D&D 5e Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide. However on page 134 he is said to sleep in a grove near the town of Triboar. I'm wondering if this means he is more of a demigod? He clearly lives on the mortal plane and is somewhat of a messenger or liaison to Mielikki, Goddess of Forests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DMG (p.11) has the following to say on demigods & lesser deities (italics are my added emphasis):

> **Lesser deities** are embodied somewhere in the planes. *Some lesser deities live in the Material Plane*, as does the unicorn-goddess Lurue of the Forgotten Realms and the titanic shark-god Sekolah revered by the sahuagin. Others live on the Outer Planes, as Lolth does in the Abyss. *Such deities can be encountered by mortals.*
>
> **Quasi-deities** have a divine origin, *but they don't hear or answer prayers, grant spells to clerics*, or control aspects of mortal life. They are still immensely powerful beings, and in theory they could ascend to godhood if they amassed enough worshipers. Quasi-deities fall into three subcategories: *demigods*, titans, and vestiges.
>
> Demigods are born from the union of a deity and a mortal being. They have some divine attributes, but their mortal parentage makes them the weakest quasi-deities.

Given the above, that the blurb on Gwaeron Windstrom on SCAG p.134 mentioned in the question describes rangers praying to him as a proxy for Mielikki, and that he is present on the Faerûnian Pantheon list (with domains), I believe it puts him firmly in the lesser deity camp rather than the demigod one.

If he was a demigod in prior editions (as another answer indicates), it's possible that either he gained enough worshipers to ascend to godhood or the definition between demigod & god changed sufficiently between editions that he falls on the other side of the fence now.